# Calling service from shell using curl. How to get result and error

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am calling a service via curl and in case of success I want to get the result in a variable. So I do this call:

```
result=$(curl -s $URL)
```

For the success case this works well. In case of an error I get just null in the variable.

In case of error the service throws some http code like 400 and returns some details in the response.

How can I also evaluate the error and fetch the error response?

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to understand what exactly you want. This is probably a duplicate of an existing question. The status code of the command will be available in `$?` and the error message is probably being printed on standard error. So something like `if result=$(curl -s "$URL" 2>&1); then echo "success: $result"; else echo "failure: $result ($?)"; fi`

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but how about redirecting stdout and stderr to different files and using the exit status of `curl` to see whether the command had an error?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. I want to be able to build an if to distinguish error and success and be able to provide the returned value in case of success and the returned error details in case of failure. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stderror to file:

```
command 2> file
```

Stderror to stdout:

```
command > file 2>&1
```

Try these flags with curl for stderror:

```
--fail --silent --show-error
```

Comment: I tried with :
result=$(curl -s $URL) 2>&1
and 
result=$(curl -s $URL 2>&1)

Still in both cases I get null in result in case of error.

 If I just do 
curl -s $URL
then I see the error on the console, but I can not get the content in success case.

Comment: Edited the post, please test...

Comment: Many thanks. That helps. In the mean time I also found that I can check the result of the curl request via $?. So I can also build an if to break execution in case of an error.